# Why is the order for some words that function as ordinal numbers flexible?

Tags: grammar, word-order, ordinal-numbers

Adjectives, numbers, and determiners have a [set order](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/determiners/determiners-position-and-order) when multiples are used to reference the same noun at once. When cardinal and ordinal numbers are used at the same time, the [ordinal always comes first](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-an-ordinal-number-1691459).

However, there are some words that seem to function as ordinals but which seem to be flexible in their order while the equivalent (true) ordinal is not:

> The **three remaining** cookies.  *- or -*  The **remaining three** cookies.
>
> The **last three** cookies.  - but NOT -  The **three last** cookies.
>
> ---
>
> The **three initial** cookies.  *- or -*  The **initial three** cookies.
>
> The **first three** cookies.  - but NOT -  The **three first** cookies.
>
> ---
>
> The **three subsequent** cookies.  *- or -*  The **subsequent three** cookies.
>
> The **next/following three** cookies.  - but NOT -  The **three next/following** cookies.

### Why do these words that function as ordinals have greater flexibility than their ordinal equivalents?

Comment: I don't agree that the *NOT* versions are never used.

Comment: @Jason You're probably right that we can't say "never" with full confidence, but those orderings are not correct according to the sources I linked and they certainly sound "off" to me, whereas the other formations do not. (Admittedly, that's a very subjective litmus test.)

Comment: Probably because all three cookies are remaining, but only one of them can be last. So "the last three cookies" is the last group of three cookies, but "the three last cookies" sounds like an oxymoron.

Comment: I think some of these sound "off" with cookies, but if you replace "cookies" with "people in line" they sound normal.

Comment: First, context makes a difference. (As per another comment.) Second, just because something is *uncommon* does not make it *incorrect*.

Comment: @Jason Hmm. I'm not seeing one that sounds correct if I use "people in line" instead of "cookies." Google Ngram doesn't find *any* instances of "[number] next [noun]" but maybe I'm [not using it right](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=two+next+_noun_%2Cthree+next+_noun_%2C+four+next+_noun_%2C+five+next+_noun_%2C+six+next+_noun_%2C+seven+next+_noun_%2C+eight+next+_noun_%2C+nine+next+_noun_&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=)?

Comment: @michael.hor257k Your comment answers the question perfectly: only one cookie can be the first, the last or the next (there can't be three that are the first, the last or the next ones at the same time). In that position, *first, last, next* modify the noun phrase formed by "three + cookies" (respectively meaning the first, the last and the next set of three cookies).

Comment: I disagree with that rule as an absolute rule, that the ordinal ALWAYS comes before the cardinal. If you search for "the two first" in Google books you get results for what we might more commonly write "the two first", either way it's understandable. You might argue that it's incorrect or old-fashioned. There's A History of India Under the Two First Sovereigns of Taimur..." published by Cambridge University Press. Furthermore "the two first" can change the meaning. "the product of the two first terms", "The two first lines have four trochees" (of verses or stanzas), and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Michael.hor257k has summed this up perfectly:

> Probably because all three cookies are remaining, but only one of them can be last. So "the last three cookies" is the last group of three cookies, but "the three last cookies" sounds like an oxymoron.